# The application does not always start in the main view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, view

I would like to my application always starts in the main view.. the problem is that when you open the first time the application starts in the main view but if I close the application when i reopen the application starts in the view that i was before close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is an option in the project plist.The option is "Application does not run in background",Make this to YES.

Answer (score 2):

Your application becomes suspended when you press the Home button; it doesn't normally get terminated. Hence, when you launch it again, it resumes from the previous state.

If you want your app to get terminated, you need to set "Application does not run in background" to YES in your target info properties (Info.plist).

If you want to run in the background but to always go to a specific view upon launch, you need to set it up in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this:

```
- (void) dropWithViewController:(UIViewController*)vc {
    if( [vc modalViewController] ){
        [self dropWithViewController:[vc modalViewController]];
        [vc dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    } else if( [vc isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] ){
        [self dropWithViewController:[(UINavigationController*) vc topViewController]];
        UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController*)vc;
        for( int i=0;i<[[nc viewControllers] count]-1;i++ ){
            [nc popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
    } else if( [vc isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]){
        [self dropWithViewController:[(UITabBarController*) vc selectedViewController]];
    } else {
        //you're at the last view, on return it will start going back
        return;
    }
}
```

And then call it like this when the app is entering background (see UIApplicationDelegate, - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application):

```
- (void )dropAllViewControllers{
    UIViewController *firstViewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow] rootViewController];
    [self dropWithViewController:firstViewController];
}
```